# After using DWM ,the text of button becomes transparent

Tags: c, windows, winapi, dwm

I am using plain C ,and here is the code :

Creating the button:

```
HWND hBTN = CreateWindow(_T("button"), _T("AAasfasdfdsa"), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON, 10, 10, 100, 100, hWnd, NULL, hInst, NULL);
```

Call DWM function:

```
DWM_BLURBEHIND bb = { 0 };
bb.dwFlags = DWM_BB_ENABLE;
bb.fEnable = true;
bb.hRgnBlur = NULL;
MARGINS margins = { -1, -1, -1, -1 };
DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(hWnd, &margins);
```

image demonstrates:

[image]

Comment: And what do you expect it to do?

Comment: [DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969512.aspx): *"Use negative margin values to create the "sheet of glass" effect [...]"*. The effect looks precisely like it should. What do you hope to expect instead?

Comment: How can I make the text to be black?

Comment: @MohitJain I suppose he wants the background of the window semi.transparent, but not the button itself.

Comment: @马拉戈壁 Did you try calling DWM function for `hBtn` with `dwFlags` set to disabled?

Comment: This seems promising: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18910/Adding-or-Retrofitting-Aero-Glass-into-Legacy-Wind

Comment: @enhzflep Thank you verrrrrrrrrrrrrry much :)

Answer (score 0):

The text becomes transparent because the black colour is treated as the transparency key.

Therefore, you just need to set another transparency key for the window:

```
SetWindowLong(hWnd,GWL_EXSTYLE,WS_EX_LAYERED);
SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hWnd,RGB(200,201,202),0,LWA_COLORKEY);
```

Comment: It only works with some colors, for example, If I use `RGB(0, 255, 0)`, the windows hides automatically when I click the window, because Windows treats the window as 'transparent' (I guess)